# Facing authentication and Permissions issue when building nginx container

Tags: authentication, docker, nginx, centos7, ansible-container

Code:
    version: '2'
    settings:
    conductor_base: centos:7
    services:
    ansible.play_container:
    from: "nginx_base"
    roles:

````
nginx_container
ports:
"xxx"
user: root
command: ['app/xxx/docker-entrypoint.sh']
registries: {}```

OS/Environment :
Ansible Container, version 0.9.2
Linux, 3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64, #1 SMP Mon Feb 29 13:22:02 EST 2016, x86_64
2.7.5 (default, May 3 2017, 07:55:04)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-14)] /usr/bin/python
````

Command used:
    Sudo ansible-container --debug build

```
Error Log:
fatal: [ansible.nginx-container]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Authentication or permission failure. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote temp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\". Failed command was: ( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1512122910.09-221104636739910 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1512122910.09-221104636739910=\"` echo ~/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1512122910.09-221104636739910 `\" ), exited with result 1, stderr output: Error response from daemon: Container c94048b2a046a9077fbff0558919ce55704e6b8634af611abe6ec2d58a2ccd18 is not running\n"
```

Please help in resolving the permissions error

Answer (score 0):

I'd be happy to try to help, however there's a lot more information needed to triage your issue. If you'd be so kind as to try to clean up the formatting of your YAML above, include the output of `ansible-container --debug version`, and include the full debug output from your build with `ansible-container --debug build` - I'll be able to be of service. Thanks!